# Esri map popup problem

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

My map works fine. Popup works fine. For some reason, the bottom of the popup window has some layout issues. I have all the resources included.

script:

```
dojo.require("esri.map");
dojo.require("esri.dijit.Popup");
```

And css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/esri.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Popup.css" type="text/css">
```

[image: Bottom is incorrectly displayed]

Do you have any suggestions on how I could debug this issue?

Comment: This question though based on a GIS based website, is really about a layout formatting problem.  I am not sure it is appropriate here.  That notwithstanding, if the window has a layout issue, it probably has something to do with the css.  Simply showing the link to the referenced css files doesn't allow us to see the formatting entries that are causing the conflict.  This would be a problem no matter which site this question is posted on.  Please post the actual `css`.

Comment: @GetSpatial: While in essence the cause of the Problem is in CSS, it has to do with ESRI's JSAPI. A lot of background knowledge is required to work with the ESRI JSAPI; If this question was posted on Stackoverflow, it would be closed there as off-topic, because it deals with third-part CSS. IMHO, it is on topic for GIS.SE, since it deals with development of GIS Softawre, and there are many ppl with expertise in this, who could help the OP out. I'm voting to keep it open.

Comment: @dam: Could you post a reproducible example on something like jsfiddle?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - Point well taken.  Hopefully the OP will provide us with some additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out one of my css classes, in this case .content, shares the same name as one of the classes used in esri.css. The part that threw it off was padding-bottom: 15px. Dumb error, but thanks for your help everyone.